# Reflection, how to get the PropertyType value and convert to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

In my solution, I have a business validation service that can be applied on any class with a base class of Entity type.

Now I need to aggregate the rules that are broken but am stuck, I have properties that can be Collections, so i need to check each item in the collection as well.

To do that I have this check

```
typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)
```

but now that i know that the type is a collection. 
How do I cast to that Type `IEnumerable<T>` so that i can proceed with the next step.

This should take as 1st parameter the item from the collection detected.

Something like this

```
foreach(var collectionItem in collection)
{
      AggregateBrokenRules(collectionItem, ref rules);
}
```

Where collection is the result of the conversion or cast

```
private void AggregateBrokenRules(Type reflectedType, ref List<BrokenRule> rules)
{
      /// => don't apply any filter of any kind except for what already is provided 
      PropertyInfo[] properties = reflectedType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

      /// => iterate through discovered properties
      foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
      {
         /// => if type is IEnumerable
         if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
         {
             /// => cast to IEnumerable 
             var propertyVal = Convert.ChangeType(types, property.PropertyType);


             AggregateBrokenRules(property.PropertyType, ref rules);
          }

          /// => only properties that are of type Entity
          if (typeof(Entity).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
          {
              /// => check next level
              AggregateBrokenRules(property.PropertyType, ref rules);
          }

           /// => get the value from this property
           object propertyValue = property.GetValue(reflectedType);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to inspect the value of the property? What do you want to inspect when it is an IEnumerable?

Comment: Are you looking to get `property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First()` perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to do. I know what I need to get. The value stored in the property as generic collection. So i think i need a IEnumerable<object>

Comment: Well `property.PropertyType` is going to give you `IEnumerable<Something>` and the code in my first comment will give you `Something`.

Comment: Try cast `(IEnumerable)propertyValue` if you're sure implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: It worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally helps if you write out a specification that describes what you want and then implement functions that handle each part. This can provide a bit more clarity up front or introduce clarity in an existing issue. For example:

A type's properties may be inspected.

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetInspectableProperties(Type type) => type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

A type may be a sequence of Entity instances.

```
bool TypeCanBeEnumeratedAsEntitySequence(Type type) => typeof(IEnumerable<Entity>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

An instance with an Entity sequence property may have the instances present in the collection retrieved.

```
IEnumerable<Entity> GetEntitiesFromProperty(object instance, PropertyInfo property) => (IEnumerable<Entity>)property.GetValue(instance);
```

An instance may be evaluated for instances that have broken the rules.

```
IEnumerable<BrokenRule> GetBrokenRulesFor(object instance)
{
    var type = instance.GetType();
    var properties = GetInspectableProperties(type);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (TypeCanBeEnumeratedAsEntitySequence(property.PropertyType))
        {
            var instanceTypesInCollection = GetEntitiesFromProperty(instance, property);
            var brokenRulesInCollection = instanceTypesInCollection.Select(x => GetBrokenRulesFor(x)).SelectMany(x => x);

            // ...
        }
    }    
}
```

You may notice that we're talking about *instances* and not *types*. Due to your interest in going through collections, it's likely that you don't care whether the structure of a particular *type* is invalid, you probably care whether you've been given a particular *instance* that either breaks the rules or contains properties *which contain instances* that break the rules.

You may want to change your aggregation method accordingly.